# Python Pygame cannot find global variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Hej,

python tells me that it cannot find the global name "SCREEN" is not defined.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\AntGame.py", line 443, in 
>       run()
>
> File "C:\Python27\AntGame.py", line 413, in run
>       ant.brain.set_state("exploring")
>
> File "C:\Python27\AntGame.py", line 65, in set_state
>       self.active_state.entry_actions()
>
> File "C:\Python27\AntGame.py", line 253, in random_destination
>       w, h = SCREEN.SIZE

here is my code. Cannot find the trick of this. I am a newbie ..

```
#its an "ant TV" simulation
 SCREEN_SIZE = (640, 480)
 NEST_POSITION = (320, 240)
 ANT_COUNT = 20
 NEST_SIZE = 100.





import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from random import randint, choice
from GamOBjects.vector2 import Vector2


screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, 32)

class State(object):

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

def do_actions(self):
    pass

def check_conditions(self):
    pass

def entry_actions(self):
    pass

def exit_actions(self):
    pass


class StateMachine(object):

def __init__(self):

    self.states = {}
    self.active_state = None

def add_state(self, state):

    self.states[state.name] = state

def think(self):

    if self.active_state is None:
        return

    self.active_state.do_actions()

    new_state_name = self.active_state.check_conditions()
    if new_state_name is not None:
        self.set_state(new_state_name)

def set_state(self, new_state_name):

    if self.active_state is not None:
        self.active_state.exit_actions()

    self.active_state = self.states[new_state_name]
    self.active_state.entry_actions()


class World(object):

def __init__(self):

    self.entities = {}
    self.entit_id = 0

    self.background = pygame.surface.Surface(SCREEN_SIZE).convert()
    self.background.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.draw.circle(self.background, (200, 255, 200), NEST_POSITION, int(NEST_SIZE))

def add_entity(self, entity):

    self.entities[self.entity_id] = entity
    entity.id = self.entity_id
    self.entity_id += 1

def remove_entity(self, entity):

    del self.entities[entity.id]

def get(self, entity_id):

    if entity_id in self.entities:
        return self.entities[entity_id]
    else:
        return None

def process(self, time_passed):

    time_passed_seconds = time_passed / 1000.0
    for entity in self.entitites.itervalues():
        entity.process(time_passed_seconds)

def render(self, surface):

    surface.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
    for entity in self.entities.values():
        entity.render(surface)

def get_close_entity(self, name, location, range=100.):

    location = Vector2(*location)

    for entity in self.entities.values():
        if entity.name == name:
            distance = location.get_distance_to(entit_location)
            if distance < range:
                return entity

    return None




class GameEntity(object):

def __init__(self, world, name, image):

    self.world = world
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.location = Vector2(0, 0)
    self.destination = Vector2(0, 0)
    self.speed = 0.

    self.brain = StateMachine()

    self.id = 0

def render(self, surface):

    x, y = self.location
    w, h = self.image.get_size()
    surface.blit(self.image, (x-w/2, y-h/2))

def process(self, time_passed):

    self.brain.think()

    if speed > 0 and self.location != self.destination:

        vec_to_destination = self.destination - self.location
        distance_to_destination = vec_to_destination.get_length()
        heading = vec_to_destination.get_normalized()
        travel_distance = min(distance_to_destination, time_passed * self.speed)
        self.location += travel_distance * heading


class Leaf(GameEntity):

def __init__(self, world, image):
    GameEntity.__init__(self, world, "spider", image)

class Spider(GameEntity):

def __init__(self, world, image):

    self.dead_image = pygame.transform .flip(image, 0, 1)

    self.health = 25
    self.speed = 50. + randint(-20, 20)

def bitten(self):

    self.health -= 1
    if self.health <= 0:
        self.speed=0.
        self.image = self.dead_image
    self.speed = 140.


def render(self, surface):

    GameEntity.render(self, surface)

    x, y = self.location
    w, h = self.image.get_size()
    bar_x = x - 12
    bar_y = y + h/2
    surface.fill( (255, 0, 0), (bar_x, bar_y, 25, 4))
    surface.fill( (0, 255, 0), (bar_x, bar_y, self.health, 4))

def process(self, time_passed):

    x, y = self.location
    if x > SCREEN_SIZE[0] + 2:
        self.world.remove_entity(self)
        return

    GameEntity.process(self, time_passed)


class Ant(GameEntity):

def __init__(self, world, image):

    GameEntity.__init__(self, world, "ant", image)

    exploring_state = AntStateExploring(self)
    seeking_state = AntStateSeeking(self)
    delivering_state = AntStateDelivering(self)
    hunting_state = AntStateHunting(self)

    self.brain.add_state(exploring_state)
    self.brain.add_state(seeking_state)
    self.brain.add_state(delivering_state)
    self.brain.add_state(hunting_state)

    self.carry_image = None

def carry(self, image):

    self.carry_image = image

def drop(self, surface):

    if self.carry_image:
        x, y = self.location
        w, h = self.carry_image.get_size()
        surface.blit(self.carry_image, (x-w, y-h/2))
        self.carry_image = None


def render(self, surface):

    GameEntit.render(self, surface)

    if self.carry_image:
        x, y = self.location
        w, h = self.carry_image.get_size()
        surface.blit(self.carry_image, (x-w, y-h/2))



class AntStateExploring(State):

def __init__(self, ant):

    State.__init__(self, "exploring")

    self.ant = ant

def random_destination(self):

    w, h = SCREEN.SIZE
    self.ant.destination = vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))

def do_actions(self):

    if randint(1, 20) ==1:
        self.random_destination()

def check_conditions(self):

    leaf = self.ant.world.get_close_entity("leaf", self.ant.location)
    if leaf is not None:
        self.ant.leaf_id = leaf_id
        return "seeking"

    spider = self.ant.world.get_close_entity("spider", NEST_POSITION, NEST_SIZE)
    if spider is not None:
        if self.ant.location.get_distance_to(spider.location) < 100.:
            self.ant.spider_id = spider.id
            return "hunting"

    return None

def entry_actions(self):

    self.ant.speed = 120. + randint(-30, 30)
    self.random_destination()



class AntStateSeeking(State):

def __init__(self, ant):

    State.__init__(self, "Seeking")

    self.ant = ant

    self.leaf_id = None


def check_conditions(self):

    leaf = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.leaf_id)
    if leaf is None:

        return "exploring"

    if self.ant.location.get_distance_to(leaf.location) < 5.0:

        self.ant.carry(image)
        self.ant.world.remove_entity
        return "delivering"



def entry_actions(self):

     leaf = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.leaf_id)
     if leaf is not None:
         self.ant.destination = leaf.location
         self.ant.speed = 160. + randint(-20, 20)

class AntStateDelivering(State):

def __init__(self, ant):

    State.__init__(self, "delivering")
    self.ant = ant

def check_conditions(self):

    if Vector2(*NEST_POSITION).get_distance_to(self.ant.location) < NEST_SIZE:
        if (randint(1, 10) == 1):
            self.ant.drop(self.ant.world.background)
            return "exploring"

    return None

def entry_actions(self):

    self.ant.speed = 60.
    random_offset = Vector2(randint(-20, 20), randint(-20, 20))
    self.ant.destination = Vector2(*NEST_POSITION) + random_offset



class AntStateHunting(State):

def __init__(self, ant):

    State.__init__(self, "hunting")

    self.ant = ant

    self.got_kill = False

def do_actions(self):

    spider = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.spider_id)

    if spider is None:
        return

    self.ant.destination = spider.location

    if self.ant.location.get_distance_to(spider.location) < 15.:

        if randint(1, 5) == 1:
            spider.bitten()

            if spider.health <= 0:
                self.ant.carry(spider.image)
                self.ant.world.remove_entity(spider)
                self.got_kill = True


def check_conditions(self):

    if self.got_kill:
        return "delivering"

    spider = self.ant.world.get(self.ant.spider_id)


    if spider is None:
         return "exploring"

    if spider.location.get_distance_to(NEST_POSITION) > NEST_SIZE * 3:
        return exploring

    return None

def entry_actions(self):

    self.speed = 160. + randint(0, 50)

def exit_actions(self):
    self.geot_kill = False

 def run():

pygame.init()


world = World()

w, h = SCREEN_SIZE

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

ant_image = pygame.image.load("ant.png").convert_alpha()
leaf_image = pygame.image.load("leaf.png").convert_alpha()
spider_image = pygame.image.load("spider.png").convert_alpha()


for ant_no in xrange(ANT_COUNT):

    ant = Ant(world, ant_image)
    ant.location = Vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))
    ant.brain.set_state("exploring")
    world.add_entity(ant)

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == QUIT:
            return

    time_passed = clock.tick(30)


    if randint(1, 10) == 1:
        leaf = Leaf(world, leaf_image)
        leaf.location = Vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))
        world.add_entity(leaf)

    if randint(1, 100) == 1:
        spider = Spider(world, spider_image)
        spider.location = Vector2(-50, randint(0, h))
        spider.destination = Vector2(w+50, randint(0,h))
        world.add_entity(spider)

    world.process(time_passed)
    world.render(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
    run()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you tried to reference the variable `SCREEN_SIZE`, but typed `SREEN.SIZE`:

```
def random_destination(self):

    w, h = SCREEN.SIZE
    self.ant.destination = vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))
```

Python assumes it has to look for an object named `SCREEN` and then return its attribute `SIZE`. `SCREEN`, however, does not exist. Change it to:

```
def random_destination(self):

    w, h = SCREEN_SIZE
    self.ant.destination = vector2(randint(0, w), randint(0, h))
```

This will unpack the contents of `SCREEN_SIZE` into `w` and `h`.

TBH, this is quite a trivial error message. Just curious ... how come you write such a big chunk of code and don't understand the traceback?

Comment: Youre right, its not my code, I got it from a book I am reading for learning programming with python/pygame.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. Good luck, then. You'll get used to these kind of errors in time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to `SCREEN.SIZE`, but the variable is clearly called `SCREEN_SIZE`.